# Background task for Workmanger

Tags: android

My question is can I close the activity after starting work manager?. currently in my app, I want to use `WorkManager` to print a receipt from the printer. So I want to start `WorkManager` from the activity, then I need to close the activity. Will the code from the `WorkManager` continue the print task from the worker or will it stop after closing the activity ?

Comment: yes you can close your activity

Comment: @nitinkumarp you should consider adding an answer then :)

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer :- Yes**

that's the whole point of the using the `workmanager` so you can schedule your task based on System events, so it does not not matter what activity is running.

as according to the documentation

> For work that is deferrable and expected to run even if your device or
>   application restarts, use WorkManager.

https://developer.android.com/guide/background/#workmanager

About how to implement `workmanager`, below documentation will help you.
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics

here at the end you will find section "**Hand off your task to the system**".

the system will place your task in a system queue to execute it based on system event that you will define